# Python color map but with all zero values mapped to black

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, color-mapping

I have a square array of elements which correspond to lattice sites. Some of the elements are zero and the rest vary between 1 and about 2700. Using imshow and the OrRd colour map, I want all lattice sites greater than 0 to display the corresponding colour but importantly, *all sites with value 0 to be displayed as black*. I have tried defining a new color map as follows:

```
colors = [(0,0,0)] + [(pylab.cm.OrRd(i)) for i in range(1,256)] 
new_map = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('new_map', colors, N=256)
```

but the range of values in my array is too large and so a lot of non-zero values get displayed as black.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The colormaps of Matplotlib have a `set_bad` and `set_under` property which can be used for this. This example shows how to use the `set_bad`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make some data
a = np.random.randn(10,10)

# mask some 'bad' data, in your case you would have: data == 0
a = np.ma.masked_where(a < 0.05, a)

# cmap = plt.cm.OrRd

# for mpl 3.3 and higher use
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap("OrRd").copy()

cmap.set_bad(color='black')

im = plt.imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

To use the `set_under` variant you have to add the `vmin` keyword to the plotting command and setting is slightly above zero (but below any other valid value):

```
cmap.set_under(color='black')    
im = plt.imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, vmin=0.0000001)
```

Comment: How can I plot a colorbar that also reflects that change (black at 0, cmap elsewhere)?

Comment: The `set_bad` value of a cmap has no representation in a colorbar for as far as I know. But if you use the `set_under` approach, it will show when showing the over/under extensions by using `extend="both"`. So, `plt.colorbar(im, extend='both')`, `im` being the capture mappable from the `imshow()` command.