# Using imshow() to represent 0 as white

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, imshow

I've looked around and haven't found a straightforward solution to this seemingly simple problem online or in the matplotlib documentation. I'm using imshow() to create a heatmap of a matrix with a diverging cmap (coolwarm), and I'd like to make 0 represented as white, positive values as red, and negative values as blue. Anyone know of an easy way to do this without creating a custom cmap?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/userdemo/colormap_normalizations_diverging.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python color map but with all zero values mapped to black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548813/python-color-map-but-with-all-zero-values-mapped-to-black)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using min-max normalization, here zero in the original data gets shifted, so shift the zero as shown below.  The below is a way I figured that can be done in this way.

```
data = np.array([[0.000000,5.67],[-0.231049,0.45],[-0.231049,0.000000]])

k=(data-np.min(data))/(np.max(data)-np.min(data)) # Min-max Normalization

nsv_zero =-np.min(data)/(np.max(data)-np.min(data))  # new shifted value of zero

sns.heatmap(np.where( k == nsv_zero ,0.5 ,k),vmin=0,vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=data)


* Min-Max Normalization : Scale all the values to new range(0,1)
* Shifting zero in initial data to 0.5 in the new output data so as to get white color
* Here I am using modified data on heatmap, but I am using the original annotations only.
```

Hope this is a bit closer to  your required output

[image]