# How to display values of an array as colored lattice points?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am creating a python program that simulates the folding of proteins. My protein is 19 elements (amino acids) long, with each element specified by a number between 1 and 20. I used `randint()` to create the protein and created an array of zeros.

The protein is initially unfolded and centered horizontally in a 21 by 21 array. So the nonzero values of the array are on the 10th row. I imported matplotlib and used `matshow()` to display this arrangement:

[image: here].

What I like about this figure is that it is apparent that the protein is made up of different amino acids/elements, as shown by color of each square. I would like to keep this feature. However, instead of squares I would like each element to show up as a colored dot connected to its neighbor by a link, or on a grid:

[image: link image] [image: on a grid like this image].

I have provided my code below. To summarize my questions:

1) How do I display the elements in an array as circles or as lattice points with links connecting the dots?

2) How do I do the above while keeping the colors the same for each element?

3) How do I specify that the zero-values (currently purple) should be white? I don't have a preference for the other colors, I would like a white background.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

###create grid
rows = 21 
columns = 21
x = np.zeros(rows) #create arrays for the x- and y-positions
y = np.zeros(columns)
middle = (rows-1)/2

grid = np.zeros((rows,columns)) #grid = [row][columns] = value = grid[j][i]

###create protein:
n = 20
protein = []
while len(protein) < n:
     a = random.randint(1, 20)
     protein = np.append(protein, a)

###specify initial condition with protein unfolded along y=0
j = int(middle)
i = 1
while i < rows-1:
    grid[j][i] = protein[i]
    i = i+1
print(grid)
plt.matshow(grid)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colored dots can be drawn with `plt.scatter()`. Straight line segments with `plt.plot()`.

To represent the folding, an array of `0`s, `1`s and `-1`s can represent the folding going straight, turning right or turning left.

To draw the plot, create `x` and `y` positions while applying the folding directions. These positions serve to draw the line segments (`plt.plot`) and as well as the colored dots (`plt.scatter`). To have 20 different colors, the 'tab20' [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) could be used.

Here is some example code to get you started.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 20
protein = np.random.randint(1, 20, n) # n numbers between 1 and 19
folds = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int) # default there are no turns
folds[9] = -1 # turn left after protein 9
folds[11] = 1 # turn right after protein 11
folds[15] = -1 # turn left after protein 15

dir = (1, 0)
pos = (0, 0)
x = np.zeros_like(protein)
y = np.zeros_like(protein)
for i, (p, f) in enumerate(zip(protein, folds)):
    x[i], y[i] = pos
    if f == 1:  # turn right
        dir = (dir[1], -dir[0])
    elif f == -1:  # turn left
        dir = (-dir[1], dir[0])
    pos = (pos[0] + dir[0], pos[1] + dir[1])
plt.plot(x, y, 'k-', zorder=0)  # straight lines
# large dots colored via the 'tab20' colormap, set zorder=3 to draw the dots on top of the lines
plt.scatter(x, y, c=protein, cmap='tab20', s=200, zorder=3) 

plt.axis('off') # don't show the axes
plt.margins(0.1) # enough margin so that the large scatter dots don't touch the borders
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal') # equal distances in x and y direction 
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To draw something similar to example 'd':

```py
n = 15
protein = np.random.randint(1, 20, n)
folds = [1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0]
```

[image: similar to example d]

PS: With the following adaptions, gridlines are shown:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, NullFormatter

plt.axis('on')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis='both', length=0)
plt.grid(True, ls=':')
```

[image: with grid]

Comment: It does! This is very insightful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Q1 & 2-
I think you're looking to add a scatter plot with different colour markers on top of your current graph. Might be tricky to add both a line and different colour markers so your best bet might be to simply add a line plot that relies on the same x/y values so that the two are updated at the same time (assuming you are updating them to display folding). Given code is just the scatter but it maintains your current colour system.

Edit: See the other answer for a great example of this (scatter and plot).

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
normalize = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=20)
mapping = cm.viridis(normalize(protein))  # maintain current colours
plt.scatter(range(20), np.broadcast_to(10, 20), c=mapping, marker='o')
```

Q3-
You can set values for a specific colourmap to display particular colours with .set_under, see for example this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552651/9754355 This should make your mapping background white.

```
cm.viridis.set_under(c='w')
plt.matshow(grid, vim=1e-9)  # Arbitrary low value.
```

If this negatively affects your protein colours consider using numpy NaN or infinty or something similar and set_bad instead.

Comment: This fixed the coloring. Thank you!